# JSON Serializable Error in Django

Tags: python, json, django, django-queryset, serializable

Two lines of code as follows:

```
record = Record.objects.get(id = request.GET.get('record_id'))
print record.unique_number
```

Error is thrown when trying to print as follows:

```
<Record: Record object> is not JSON serializable
```

Traceback is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 235, in get_response
    response = middleware_method(request, response)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/middleware.py", line 50, in process_response
    request.session.save()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 82, in save
    obj = self.create_model_instance(data)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/db.py", line 68, in create_model_instance
    session_data=self.encode(data),
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/sessions/backends/base.py", line 88, in encode
    serialized = self.serializer().dumps(session_dict)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/signing.py", line 95, in dumps
    return json.dumps(obj, separators=(',', ':')).encode('latin-1')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 250, in dumps
    sort_keys=sort_keys, **kw).encode(obj)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 207, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 270, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/encoder.py", line 184, in default
    raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <Record: Record object> is not JSON serializable
```

The Record class is defined as follows in models.py:

```
class Record(models.Model):
    unique_number = models.CharField(max_length = 255)
    year = models.SmallIntegerField()

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'demo'
        db_table = 'record'
```

How do I resolve this? Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think it's the `print` that give you the error. Can you edit your question to show the full traceback?

Comment: You are correct. It's not the print function but the access of the unique_number property on the Record object (i.e. record.unique_number).

Comment: That's not anything more useful than your original post. You need to show us the trackback and the code when error happens.

Comment: I've provided the traceback.

Comment: Are you putting the `record` in your session?

Comment: please share more detail of your code.

Comment: No, all I'm doing is calling the database, retrieving a single Record object based on an ID, and then trying to access the unique_number property of that object. The object is being returned correctly from the database.

Comment: @Foobar:  can you please paste the full definition of the `Record` class?

Comment: I've added it to my post.

Comment: I solved it by adding the following to settings.py: SESSION_SERIALIZER = 'django.contrib.sessions.serializers.PickleSerializer'